# AD / IIS Single sign-on issue with fully qualified domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

We have an issue for our intranet site that is running in our local network.

In a nutshell, we have integrated Active Directory authentication with our application and what to use IIS integrated authentication to allow users to sign on without entering any credentials.

Assume the AD domain is "domain.name", and the server our application is hosted on is "server-name". We are running in Windows 2008 and the Integrated Authentication role is set up in IIS.

We have managed to make this work for http:||server-name/, however when we enter http:||server-name.domain.name/, users are prompted for their credentials in the standard way and if they cancel, a "401 Unauthorised" message is displayed.

The issue is, that it seems to authenticate when the machine name is accessed, but browsers do not pass over credentials when the fully qualified address is accessed.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there any advice they can shed on the situation? I ask as a programmer who has little experience with network setup and Active Directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in IE settings. Tools > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Custom Level.  Scroll down to the very last setting "Automatic login only in Intranet zone".  By default IE will only automatically pass along windows authenticated credentials to a site it considers "intranet".

Comment: Is there any way to change what IE considers "intranet"?

Comment: On that same dialog click the 'Sites' > 'Advanced'.  You can use domain policy to update this for all the PCs on your network.